# Cannot import JavaScript files in a JavaScript UWP project

Tags: javascript, import, uwp

I am trying to use `import` functionality in a JavaScript UWP project so that I can divide my programs into smaller modules.

I create a basic Blank Project via Visual Studio 2017. I choose the April update for minimum and target SDK versions. This gives me a `main.js` and `index.html`.

First, I add my own JavaScript file named `mymodule.js`. The content of `mymodule.js` is like this:

```
export default function sum(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I change the `main.js` content to:

```
import { sum } from './mymodule';


window.onload = function () {
    const result = sum(2, 3);
    console.log(result);
};
```

And finally, I add `type="module"` to main.js include line on my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App2</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="module">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, nothing is written to console. Also, I cannot put breakpoints to main.js anymore. It says "No symbols have been loaded for this document".

If I remove the import line and replace the call to `sum()` function with a literal, everything works as expected.

So something goes wrong but no error message is given by Visual Studio or console. What might be the problem?

Comment: Import/export is from ES6 which is not supported in UWP.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Ok, thank you very much. Maybe you can write it as an answer so that I select it as an answer.

Comment: OK. I will write an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import/export is from ES6 which is not supported in UWP platform.